# What is the added advantage of a broker being a member of NFA in addition to IIROC

Tags: united-states, canada, insurance, broker, regulation

If my broker is a member of the national futures association, what extra protection does it give me over the fact that it is also a member of IIROC?  I am particularly referring to this:
http://www.oanda.com/corp/story/regulatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows that in each market (US and Canada) the company is registered with the appropriate regulatory organization.

OANDA is registered in the US with the National Futures Association which is a "self-regulatory organization for the U.S. derivatives industry".

OANDA Canada is registered in Canada with IIROC which is the "Investment Industry Regulatory Organization of Canada".

The company does business in both the US and in Canada so the US arm is registered with the US regulatory organization and the Canadian arm is registered with the Canadian regulatory organization.